# Webshims - Show invalid form fields on initial load

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js, webshim

(Follow on questions from [Placeholder Hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16469241/webshims-placeholder-is-being-hidden-when-appending-dynamic-content))

I'd like my form to validate existing data when it is loaded.  I can't seem to get that to happen

- I jQuery.each of my controls and call focus() and blur(), is there a better way than this?  I tried to call ctrl.checkValidity(), but it wasn't always defined yet.  When it was, it still didn't mark the controls.
- I seem to have a timing issue too, while the focus and blur() fire, the UI does not update.  It's as if the Webshims are not fully loaded yet, even though this fires in the $.webshims.ready event.
- I also tried to call $('#form').submit(), but this doesn't fire the events as I expected.  The only way I could make that happen was to include an input type='submit'.  How can I pragmatically case a form validation like clicking a submit button would?

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ttubbs/FKf35/) that demonstrates the problem.  When the form loads, I want the invalid email to be marked as such.  If you click the add button it will be marked then, but not when initially loaded.  Why?

- Focus and blur in the control will cause it to be marked.
- BUT, clicking ADD will too (which runs the same method that ran when it was loaded).  Why does it work the 2nd time, but not when initially loaded?

  ```
  updateValidation : function ()  {
  this.$el.find('[placeholder]').each(function (index, ctrl) {  
      var $ctrl = $(ctrl);
      if( $ctrl.val() !== "" && (ctrl.checkValidity && !ctrl.checkValidity()) ) {
          // alert('Do validity check!');
          $ctrl.focus();
          $ctrl.blur();
      }
  });
  }
  ```

I see this in FF 17.0.5.  The problem is worse in IE9, sometimes taking 2 or 3 clicks of ADD before the fields show in error.  However, I get errors on some of the js files I've liked 'due to mime type mismatch'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with the fact, that you are trying to reuse the .user-error class, which is a "shim" for the CSS4 :user-error and shouldn't be triggered from script. The user-error scripts are loaded after onload or as soon as a user seems to interact with an invalid from.

From my point of view, you shouldn't use user-error and instead create your own class. You can simply check for validity using the ':invalid' selector:

```
$(this)[ $(this).is(':invalid') ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('invalid-value');
```

Simply write a function with similar code and bind them to events like change, input and so on and call it on start.

In case you still want to use user-error, you could do the following, but I would not recommend:

```
$.webshims.polyfill('forms');
//force webshims to load form-validation module as soon as possible
$.webshims.loader.loadList(['form-validation']);
//wait until form-validation is loaded
$.webshims.ready('DOM form-validation', function(){
    $('input:invalid')
        .filter(function(){
            return !!$(this).val();
        })
        .trigger('refreshvalidityui')
    ;
});
```

Comment: Perfect! The 1st option works great!  Very concise code too - I like it.  While I get you don't recommend the 2nd choice, would this be the technique to mimic an input type submit as well?

Comment: I don't really understand, what you want exactly. The native validation UI is only showing up on a user submit or a scripted type="submit" click. The second choice mimics the :user-error pseudo, which means the field is invalid + touched by the user.